# Use JavaScript to get Google Sheet ID from URL

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm currently using an input that parses a Google Sheet ID and inserts into code.

```
let sheetIdInput = document.getElementById('sheetidinput');

let id = sheetIdInput.value;
```

I want users to be able to paste the entire Google Sheet URL into this input `sheetidinput` and it to only use the Sheet ID from the URL.

Example Google Sheet URL is

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132SaKuLRdHcwEKhhQVOKd2_3j30nFvQbTgplh4nPZOg/edit#gid=0
```

The Sheet ID is between `.../d/` and `/edit...` in this case `132SaKuLRdHcwEKhhQVOKd2_3j30nFvQbTgplh4nPZOg`

This pattern repeats itself in all Google Sheet URLS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex to do it :

```
let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132SaKuLRdHcwEKhhQVOKd2_3j30nFvQbTgplh4nPZOg/edit#gid=0";
let capturedId = url.match(/\/d\/(.+)\//)

console.log(capturedId[1])
// prints : 132SaKuLRdHcwEKhhQVOKd2_3j30nFvQbTgplh4nPZOg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```js
var re = /.*\/d\/(.*)\/edit.*/;
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132SaKuLRdHcwEKhhQVOKd2_3j30nFvQbTgplh4nPZOg/edit#gid=0
";
var match = url.match(re);
var id = match[1]
//Use id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the above solutions both work well for your situation, I am adding this one as well:

```js
let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/132SaKuLRdHcwEKhhQVOKd2_3j30nFvQbTgplh4nPZOg/edit#gid=0";
let matches = /\/([\w-_]{18,})\/(.*?gid=(\d+))?/.exec(url);
console.log("spreadsheet id " + matches[1]);
console.log("sheet id " + matches[3]);
```

The `matches` makes use of regex in the following way:

- the first capturing group is used to return the `id` of the spreadsheet by matching any word character and also assuming that the id has more than 18 characters;
- the second and third capturing group is used to return the `id` of the sheet by matching the characters after `gid`.

#### Reference

- [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).